# What is the name of this structured string?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

In mysql I can see a lot of these structured strings (it's like json but not really):

```
a:2:{s:5:"hello";s:0:"";s:7:"World !";s:0:"";}
```

Does it have a special name?

It is possible to recalculate automatically the length of strings (after search and replace)?

Comment: It's serialized..... use unserialize() to recreate the array (in this case), manipulate then serialize() again..... don't try and search/replace "in situ"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a serialized string in PHP - check out the serialize() and unserialize() functions in the documentation:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php

You can't really edit them inline (at least I wouldn't recommend it) - your best bet would be to userialize(), make the change to the array, and then re-serialize() the array.

Comment: I can't unserialze and serialize throught php. I need to do it in sql (or through sql file). It's cause of new domain name of a website present in theses kind of strings.

Comment: @Inglebard - if this is a one-off thing, you might be better off copying the text out of the database and into a quickly written PHP program to unserialise it; do the changes; and print out the new serialised version, so you can paste it back into the database. You can edit it direct in the database, but it's very, very easy to get it wrong.

Comment: If you search and replace directly, then unserializing will fail (very likely). For example, if you replace "hello" with "hi", then you'd also need to change "s:5" into "s:2", because the length of the string has changed from 5 to 2 characters ("s" means "string", "a" means "array", and so on). I'd strongly recommend writing a script that would fetch the rows that require changes, then unserialize the data, do the replace, then serialize and save. Anything else leads to a very thin line to breaking the website into pieces.